# Changing Back Design On The Latest Ubuntu To Older Version!

Tags: software-center, directory

I am using **Ubuntu 17.04** atm and I then noticed a few changes in it's Layout & Design. Unfortunately I prefer how it was on the older versions of Ubuntu.

*Example 1:* **Ubuntu Software** Center,
I really liked that the **Search Bar** was always open and ready to go.
On later versions of Ubuntu it's "Hidden" in the top right side corner, so you have to open it manually before you can start searching. It's not about being lazy, but about working fast since the only thing I use the Software Center for is Searching for Softwares. Also I think the look of the Software Center looked better before as a whole (It looks more boring now).

*Example 2:* **Folders**,
My folders have become a totaly mess! The Headlines was adapted to match the older versions of the folders and have now become so compressed that I can't even see what it's named anymore and because of this compress folders have also changed places, so what used to be on the 4th line is now on the second line and so on.

Shortly said, I prefer how it was and is now wondering if there's any way this can be changed back?

*Best Regards!*

Comment: Nothing to do about it. In example 1 you're talking about two completely different apps and the old one is gone. Period. In your second example that depends on the updtream, it's not software that Canonical can control, it's GNOME software (and their devs have a personal view on how it should look&feel, they couldn't care less about you).

Comment: That was a really boring attitude :( If that's the case I might change to another OS. I totally understand that they try new looks and such. But having the doors open since we're all different is not a bad thing. I can live with the Software Center change, however changing so the user not being able to read what they named their folders was a big mistake in my opinion.